# Using scrollTop() to get position but it is also scrolling the page

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, scrolltop

Having an issue when getting the page position using scrollTop(). I am getting the position correctly but it is also causing the underlying page to scroll back to the top (see below). I have tried two ways:

```
var page_position = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#main-body').prepend(data.image).css('margin-top', page_position + 'px');
```

and:

```
$('#main-body').prepend(data.image).css('margin-top', $(document).scrollTop() + 'px');
```

What the data.image is is a div along with an image (large screenshot) that is returned from an ajax call. The div with the image is positioning correctly but as I mentioned above the underlying page is scrolling back to the top.

BTW, I am using Foundation and the jQuery that came packaged with it, I also tried is using jquery-1.11.3.min.js with the same results.

Comment: Update: I just noticed that not only is the page scrolling up but there is a large block of white space being added to the #main-body div.

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle or CodePen example?

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript, but will do what you want:

```
var page_position = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Comment: Believe it or not that code is doing the exact same thing. I am starting to believe this is a Foundation problem, not a jQuery problem.

Answer (score 0):

Me be me I completely overlooked how I was adding the margin. I was adding it to the element I was adding the DIV to, not the DIV itself.